# How to stop slider rotation at onclick event in Jquery Cycle plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I am working with jquery cycle plugin and my slider contains embedded video. Now I need the plugin behavior such that when a user clicks on the video slide the slider should stop and plays the video. Currently the video starts playing but it goes away as slider starts to rotate again. Here is my code:

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({
    fx:     'scrollHorz',
    timeout: 7000,
    next: '#nextVideo',
    prev: '#prevVideo',
    pause:  1

});
```

Currently it pauses on hover. But I want it to be stopped once clicked.

Someone suggested this solution:

```
$('.slideshow').click(function(){
   $(this).cycle('id').cycle('pause');
});
```

With this solution problem is it stops the slider and plays the video but slider next/previous buttons also stop working.

Therefore I am looking for a proper solution. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this in your click event

`$('id').cycle('pause'); /*Stop the Cycle plugin*/`

This is the right way to do that

```
$('.slideshow').click(function(){
  $('id').cycle('pause');
});
```